# OrientDB change class of edge in java

Tags: java, orientdb

Is it possible to change the class of an OrientDB edge in java? The OrientVertex class has a "moveToClass" method but OrientEdge does not. Simply using

```
edge.setProperty("@class","newClass")
```

also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no refactoring for edges right now, but if you open a new issue we'll take care of it soon. Open it on: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, I made the issue @ https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5062